# How do you increase the flow rate for the bottom layers only in Bambu Studio?

Tags: slicing, bambu

I'm moving from a Creality printer to a Bambu printer using Bambu studio.

I often do prints with large flat top surfaces upside down on the bed, and increase the flow rate for the bottom layers only so that the filament from each pass flows more smoothly into the next. Which achieve an effect similar to ironing.

For example, increasing the flow rate to 110% on the first 3 layers printed

I'm not able to find the option to do this in Bambu studio.

Is this option missing, called something else, or simply somewhere that I haven't found yet?